Express a diagonal $3 \times 3$ matrix using the (powers) of traces
I have a $3 \times 3$ diagonal matrix which can be written as
\begin{equation}
\bf{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & A_2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & A_3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
I wonder if there is a general way to express $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$ using $tr({\bf{A}}^k)$, where $k = 1, 2, \cdots$
The reason for doing so is that the elements in $\bf{A}$ are not objective, so I need to describe them using some objective quantities (invariants).

With Newton-Girard identities (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), you may compute the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of A, and maybe find the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}$ back. I know it is not a definitive answer, but it might help you, I hope.

@Kolakoski54 It kind of is the answer, though. Newton's identities are an effective procedure to go back and forth between the sums of powers and the elementary symmetric polynomials, therefore the problem is as hard as finding the roots of a polynomial of degree the order of the matrix (in this case, $3$).

Obviously you can't express the triple $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$. At best you must remove the order, i.e., look for the function $x\mapsto \lvert (A_\bullet)^{-1}(x)\rvert$.
